# $\int\left|e^{i\langle s-t,x\rangle}-1\right|^2\mu(dx)=2(1-\Re(\varphi_\mu(s-t)))$ for all finite measures $\mu$ with $\mu(\mathbb{R}^n)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let

- $\mathcal{B}(E)$ denote the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$
- $\mu :\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\to [0,\infty)$ be a measure with $\mu(\mathbb{R}^n)=1$
- $\varphi$ be the characteristic function of $\mu$, i.e. $$\varphi(t):=\int e^{i\langle t,x\rangle}\mu(dx)$$

How can we prove that $$\int\left|e^{i\langle s-t,x\rangle}-1\right|^2\mu(dx)=2\left(1-\Re\left(\varphi(s-t)\right)\right)$$
for all $s,t\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from the equalities
\begin{align}
|\exp( i\theta )-1| ^2&=|\cos\theta-1 +i\sin\theta|^2\\
&= (1-\cos \theta)^2+(\sin\theta)^2\\
&=1- 2\cos\theta +(\cos\theta) ^2+(\sin\theta)^2\\
&=2(1-\cos\theta).
\end{align}
use this with $\theta =\langle s-t,x\rangle$ and integrate with respect to $x$.